# How to run .exe file in LINUX env using putty? [Offline]

Tags: linux, putty, redhat-enterprise-linux

Am looking for solution to run .exe. file inside my LINUX server which has no internet access.

I can't install WINE package to run the file. I am unable to find an offline package for WINE to be file transferred [PSCP] into my LINUX server.

Any help is appreciated. My LINUX OS is RHEL LINUX 7.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a legal copy of RHEL you can ask the RHEL support.
You didnot tell what kind of .exe you plan to run (need windows or not; with or without need of I/O). Wine is one possiblity, the next are kvm-qemu or dosemu. You can look for **rpm** packages on [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net) or other site for rpm search or [sf.net](http://sf.net) or you can try to look at [wine project home page](http://www.winehq.org). The closest OS to RHEL is its free version Fedora.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have downloaded wine-3.0.2.tar.xz and transfered the file over the my RHEL server using PSCP. I have unpacked the file, into a folder called wine-3.0.2. Does anyone know how to install wine from here on using PuTTY? Have tried to use .\install.sh which is located in wine-3.0.2 -> tools but PuTTY responds with "no input file specified".

Comment: Packages .tar.gz or  .tar.xz usualy content the program sources and shoud be compiled. Look for .rpm binary package (check the arch - 32bit or 64bit) for RHEL or at least Fedora. Consult the manual of rpm command (I cannot help you - I use apt-get on debian) and the install procedure will check the dependences (look if you have all necessary libraries) itself.